# Why doesn't this SSRS Windows authentication work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, reporting-services

1. I have a SSRS Express 2012, SQL Express 2012 DB and a ASP.NET 4.5 application , all in the same box.The application actually uses

> Forms authentication

. In SSRS i gave Admin rights to user

> NTAUTHORITY/IUSR

2. The web.config of the web app, the SSRS Web service and the SSRS Report manager all have `<authentication mode="Windows" />` and `<identity impersonate="true" />`
3. The Service Account is

> Local System

4. The authentication types in rsreportserver.config are `<RSWindowsNegotiate />` and `<RSWindowsKerberos />` and `<RSWindowsNTLM />`
5. In IIS 7, the web site has `ASP.NET Impersonation` and `Windows Authentication` enabled, all others disabled
6. The database uses Windows authentication. I have created a Login called

> NTAUTHORITY/IUSR

and given that Login, the rights to the database used

7. When i run the report from the application i get the error

> The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your
>   connection information and that the report server is a compatible
>   version.  An anonymous identity cannot perform an impersonation

8. The Report viewer in the ASP.NET has code as follows

   ```
           public class ReportCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
           {

           public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string userName, out string password,
               out string authority)
           {
               authCookie = null;
               userName = null;
               password = null;
               authority = null;

               return false;
           }

           public WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
           {
               get { return (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity; }
           }

           public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
           {
               get { return null; }
           }


       }
   ```

Comment: "In IIS 7, the web site has ASP.NET authentication enabled, all others disabled", I suspect this is your problem,I think you need to enable Windows authentication as well.

Comment: @BenRobinson I added Windows auth as well as you suggested. Now ReportViewer shows up , does not show report but gives error "The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version. Safe handle has been closed"

Comment: Who is the IIS application Pool user ? Try to remove Windows Auth and impersonation from IIS web site and specify a user with valid auth for DB SQL and SSRS

Comment: @Max As far as i know IIS returns user as NTAUTHORITY/IUSR. The idea was to stay away from using a specific user and depend on service account.

Comment: Each WebSite (Application) has a application pool associated where you specify many things including user, better to use a specific user of domain instead of built-in users. IIS present appPool user when impersonate == false.

Comment: @Max Thanks, but i already have one version running with my colleagues user name and password embedded in the web.config. Problem is we have to reset password every few days due to security policy. It is also risky since it exposes his credentials. Now i have to replace it in IIS ?

Comment: Never specify password in clear text ! You have to specify on services and app pool, you must ask to your system admin to create a service credentials without password expiration. Config services and apps with build in credentials is not a recommended approach from MS.